# Completion Block in Parse After View Controller is Popped Off Navigation Stack in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, automatic-ref-counting

I'm currently using Parse as the backend for a mobile app I'm developing.  The documentation recommends saving items in the background and providing a completion block after the save is complete like this:

```
var someObject = PFObject(className: "SomeObject")
someObject.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {
    (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    if (success) {
        //saved
        //call another method in this view controller
    } else {
        //error
    }
}
```

I'm doing this in a method in a view controller that is part of a navigation controller.

My question is this: In the execution block, if I added a call to another method in the view controller to, let's say, update the view with some new data, and the view is already gone or dismissed because the user went back to the previous view before the execution block gets called, will it result in a crash because the view controller is gone or deallocated at this point?  Or will the view controller remain in memory until the block is complete even though the view is not currently displayed and popped off the navigation stack?

Using iOS 9, Swift 2.1 and Parse 1.9. Also, if it helps, I know that the execution block is executed on the main thread.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will do whatever you want. You just have to code it up correctly.

So for example:

```
someObject.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {
    (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    if (success) {
        self.someFunction()
    } else {
        //error
    }
}
```

The above will cause the view controller to hang around in memory until *after* `someFunction()` returns. You probably don't want this, but if you do, that's how to do it. If you *don't* want that then:

```
someObject.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {
    [weak self] (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    if (success) {
        self?.someFunction()
    } else {
        //error
    }
}
```

With the above code, if the view controller is exited, and thus deleted, before the block is called, `someFunction` will *not* get called because `self` will be nil.

To learn more about this construct, look up "Capture Lists" in The Swift Programming book https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Expressions.html

Comment: Thank you.  That's what I was looking for.

Comment: @DuncanC None of that code is valid Objective-C. It's Swift code.

Comment: @DanielT Oops. Now I feel stupid. That'll teach me to just scan an answer. What kind of construct is the `[weak self]` syntax in Swift though?

Comment: @DuncanC It's called a capture list. I put more information in the answer.

Comment: Oh, that's right! I haven't done any significant Swift since Swift 2.0 went GM so I'm starting to forget it. :( That syntax looks like an Objective-C method call, which is what sent me off into left field.